# Como leer valores de un json que extrae datos de influxdb

Tags: php, html, json, parsear

estoy haciendo una consulta a una base de datos influxdb y al final tengo un resultado como este:

```
stdClass Object ( 
[results] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[statement_id] => 0 
[series] => Array (
[0] => stdClass Object (
[name] => custom 
[tags] => stdClass Object ( 
[hostname] => linux001 ) 
[columns] => Array (
 [0] => time [1] => 
 cpu [2] => mem [3] 
 => load [4] => load )
[values] => Array (
 [0] => Array ( [0] => 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z [1] => 1 [2] => 78 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) ) )) )
) )
```

Pero ahora quiero por ejemplo tener una tabla como esta:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
    .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
    .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
    .tg .tg-s268{text-align:left}
    .tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
    </style>
    <table class="tg">
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-s268">hostname</th>
        <th class="tg-s268">time</th>
        <th class="tg-s268">cpu</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">mem</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">load</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-s268">linux001</td>
        <td class="tg-s268">1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</td>
        <td class="tg-s268">1</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">78</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

El problema es que no logro construir la tabla, no se como iterar sobre esos elementos, soy nuevo con json. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Buenas Alberto. ¿Cual es tu duda?  Explica lo que has intentdo y tus problemas concretos siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: Hola, es que no logro construir la tabla, no se como iterar sobre esos elementos, soy nuevo con json

Comment: Básicamente lo que tienes según muestras es un objeto, para acceder a sus propiedades se utiliza el operado `->propiedad` algunas de esas propiedades contienen valores escalares, otros objetos y Arrays, para los Array debes utilizar los corchetes `[indice]`

Comment: Tu podrías darme un ejemplo para obtener el hostname? Gracias.